Access url parameters in Azure AD callback in [...nextauth] callbacks - next js
I want to access url parameters in  Azure AD callback in [...nextauth] callbacks
This is my login form
const handleAzureSignIn = () => {   
signIn('azure-ad', { callbackUrl: `${window.location.origin}/api/auth/callback/azure-ad?tenantId=${tenantId}` });
};

Here I have passed the tenentId with the callback URL. Then I want to access from the tenentId in the [...nextauth] after the authentication
callbacks: {
      async signIn({ user, account, profile }) {
      if (account.provider === 'azure-ad') {
    
   //need to access the parameter here

      if (user) {
        return { ...azureUser, ...userRes }; //userRes;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  // For other providers, return true to continue the sign in process.
  return true;
},

